# MS-Word equation editor: How do I add an exponent to the left of its base

Tags: ms-word

In spectroscopy it's common to have [expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol) like

[image]

I need to insert the superscript "2" from the picture, *within* an equation.

However in MS-Word equation editor, I can only add exponents to the *right* of its base. I also cannot just arbitrarily add an exponent without a base, so I can't simply type "^2P"

Anyone know a way to do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Seems to work fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkfGI.png). (phone screenshot, sorry)

I tried inserting the thing with sub and superscripts on the left, selected it, and then inserted the thing with the scripts on the right, and it seems to work.

If all else fails, and the equation doesn't have to be editable, you could use an online LaTeX editor to write the equation, save it as an image file, and paste into your document.
Plenty of them around, this is the first result from ddg: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: Ah I see! That is an option too. Do you know how to hide the empty boxes afterward? I seem to recall having done this with matrices, but I can't find a similar option for this case. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, I assumed the empty boxes do not show outside the equation editor (I don't use Word). Not sure if there's an intelligent way of doing it, but putting spaces in the empty ones seems to do the trick.

Comment: Yep that works perfectly fine, thank you! What do you use in preference of Word by the way?

Comment: I use LaTeX for everything I need to write.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround found here: https://superuser.com/questions/1230648/how-to-write-superscripts-before-symbols-in-equation-mode-in-ms-word/1230654

Type "^2 P " (with a space between 2 and P), which will put the 2 in superscript in front of the P, but will also add a dashed box for a subscript.

[image]

Then comes the workaround: type a space in the square! It'll disappear.